# If $\ (1+3x+x^2)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_r x^r\ $ then...

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, divisibility

If $$\ (1+3x+x^2)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_r x^r\ $$
Then then what is the least number except 1 which divides the following:$$\ \sum_{r=0}^{20}(3r+1)a_r\ $$

EDIT:
i have put x=1 then it is something like this:
$$\ 5^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_r x^r\ $$

$$\ 5^{10}=\ a_0 x^0+a_1x^1+...+a_{20}x^{20}\    $$
Now,  simplifying $$\ \sum_{r=0}^{20}(3r+1)a_r\ $$ we get:
$$\ \sum_{r=0}^{20}3ra_r+\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_r\ $$ 
$$\ 3 \sum_{r=0}^{20}ra_r+\ 5^{10}\ $$ 
After this I am unable to solve

Comment: What about 1 ;)

Comment: Ohk sorry...its exept one :)

Comment: You have previously asked questions that have been closed for the reason that you have not provided your own thoughts, efforts, or attempts to answer the question, yet you continue to post questions without context.  This is against the community guidelines.

Comment: Hint: suppose you started with the simpler question about $\sum a_r$. What would be your answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives 
$$10\ (1+3x+x^2)^{9}(2x+3)=\sum_{r=0}^{20}ra_r x^{r-1}\ $$
Multiply this by $3$ and add to the original expression to get
$$30\ (1+3x+x^2)^{9}(2x+3)+(1+3x+x^2)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}3ra_r x^{r-1}+\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_r x^r$$
$$=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_rx^{r-1}(3r+x)$$
Since $x$ is an arbitrary number, its value doesn't matter. What happens if $x=1$?